# Correct way to compare algorithm cost

Tags: algorithm, compare, signal-processing, real-time, computer-science

What's the correct way to compare the computing resources required by signal-processing algorithms?

I'm talking about signal processing algorithms that have an *error bounds vs. resources vs. response delay* compromise.

After achieving an error bound and response delay with an algorithm implementation, I'm trying to compare its efficiency.

Currently I'm benchmarking different algorithms by feeding them with the same signal and using `perf` to get the **task-clocks / mseg** used on amd64, but that's not architecture agnostic.

Industry uses MFLOPS/Hz to compare processors but how do I include memory ( and possibly threading ) overhead for an specific implementation?

What's the correct **academic** measurement to be able to say:

> Algorithm X is N times better than Y to achieve P with Q bounds.

---

**EDIT:** For context, the signal processing algorithms I'm dealing with, are iterative ones, whose step functions can be bound by O(1). So BigO seem of no use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accurate performance measures are not architecture or implementation agnostic.  Different DSP computation platforms will not only have different absolute performance numbers (MHz/GHz), but different ratios of MAC or flop latency to dispatch ratios and memory latency to bandwidth ratios, as well as many other performances hazards (cache replacement vs. streaming policies, etc.) and efficiencies (SMP or vector dispatch, etc.)

In ancient times (VAX, FP systems, 56000, or earlier) raw multiplies or MAC counts predominated over all other performance limitations, so that became the defacto cost metric.  This is no longer always the dominating factor on the modern pipelined short-vector FPU multi-processors now common inside even toys.

One possibility is to guess the platform(s) that your algorithm most likely targets, and measure on that (more likely similar to an ARM based mobile phone or Raspberry Pi system than an AMD desktop IMHO, or maybe even an OpenCL GPU).

Another possibility is to run on an academic CPU simulator (RISC V?) where you can turn on detailed performance counters (ops of each type dispatched, memory traffic, register reuse hazards, and etc.)  That will be far more accurate than any AMD desktop where OS task switching, TLB/MMU misses, and variations in cache initialization and traffic can cause all kinds of unknown variations in any performance measurements.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was fearing. Thought of using AMD because it would make it easier to reproduce the tests. Computational performance was never shown on the publications of the algorithms I'm studying, and I wanted to know how it's usually conveyed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple right answers to this. You should consider at least these two:

- Computer science uses [O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) – Usually to measure processing requirements but it's just math and can be applied to memory as well.
- Benchmarking, as you have done, is the right way to test an implementation. But you'd want to do a multivariate analysis (i. e. test it on different plattforms, input sizes etc).

In principle, the platform should only be a constant factor. But in practices, constant factors can be relevant.

Comment: Big O doesn't seem useful. I'm not interested in how my algorithm scales asymptotically, but how it behaves for my specific implementation. Input size variation would show architecture specific optimisation, and what I'm looking for is a benchmarking reference shared by the Academic Community.